# String match from beginning of string in REG Query batch script

Tags: regex, batch-file, pattern-matching, registry

I am writing a batch script to scrub the registry on a computer and return any keys which have data which match a certain value.

currently I have this:

```
REG Query HKLM /s /f AA* /d
```

However this returns keys who's data contains the partial string "AA" anywhere within the data. I would like to only return those whose data **begins** with "AA". I tried using ^AA* as my pattern in a quick regex attempt, but it does not appear to be supported. A point in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: I suppose that piping the matches to `FindStr` would be an option, but my advice is to consider using a regular expression in powershell.

Comment: I'm embarrassed to ask, but does XP support powershell?

Comment: Yes, although it may need to be installed, I think v2 is available for sp3. I'd also add that if you don't want to wait a long time for the results you'd be better off being more specific with regards the starting key, just HKLM seems unrealistic.

Comment: Installing new media into the image is not an option, or a trivial one in this case

Comment: I was able to find that powershell is installed in the machine I am using has powershell installed (major version 2, minor 0, build -1, revision -1). Could you post an answer for using regex in powershell?